# codeigniter and jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

i have some problem with the basicly function of jquery autocomplete in codeigniter but i think that the error isnt jquery

the code:

**the view:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();>application/libraries/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>application/libraries/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>application/libraries/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#client_name').autocomplete({
                source: "<?php echo site_url('site/check_in_client/?'); ?>"
            });
        });
    </script>
    <input type="text" name="client_name" id="client_name" placeholder="nome"/>
```

**the model:**

```
function check_in_client($name) {
   $this->db->like('name',$name, 'both');
   $query = $this->db->get('client');
   return $query->result();    
}
```

**the controller:**

```
function check_in_client() {
    $this->load->library('javascript');
    $this->load->view('check_in_client');
    if(isset($_GET['term'])) {
        $result= $this->membership_model->check_in_client($_GET['term']);
        if(count($result) > 0) {
            foreach($result as $pr) 
                $arr_result[] = $pr->name;
            echo json_encode($arr_result);
        }
    }
}
```

the code load a view with a blank text boxe
where is the problem?

thanks a lot by

Comment: Did you tested if the "$_GET" variable is set with any value?
You can try $this->input->get_post(). This is a CI's native method.

Answer (score 1):

In your view file:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jqueryui.css">
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#client_name').autocomplete({
                source: "<?php echo site_url('site/check_in_client/?'); ?>"
            });
        });
    </script>
    <input type="text" name="client_name" id="client_name" placeholder="nome"/>
```

In your Model:

```
 function check_in_client($name) {
       $this->db->select('name',false);
       $this->db->like('name',$name, 'both');
       $query = $this->db->get('client');
      if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $datas[] = $row->name;
            }

            echo json_encode($datas);
        } else {
            $datas[] = 'Oops! No suggestions found. Try a different search.';
            echo json_encode($datas);
        } 
    }
```

In your Controller:

```
function check_in_client() {
    $this->load->library('javascript');
    $this->load->view('check_in_client');
    if(isset($_GET['term'])) {
        $result= $this->membership_model->check_in_client($_GET['term']);

    }
}
```

Comment: now java function with no problem but the code isnt correct, I get No search results. in the text boxe always

Comment: Worked perfectly, even solved my problem of encoding. Thanks.